# Cannot see log from gRPC functions if run gRPC server with Flask app

Tags: python, flask, grpc

I'm building a microservice with a gRPC server with a Flask app in the same python file. . When testing, I can successfully receive responses from gRPC functions. But I can't see any logs from gRPC functions. Here is the code when I started my server using Flask app (I even used print() in gRPC functions)

```
def run_grpc_server():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    post_service_pb2_grpc.add_PostServiceServicer_to_server(PostService(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50054')
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    grpc_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_grpc_server)
    grpc_thread.start()

    try:
        app.run(debug=True, port=POST_PORT)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        grpc_thread.join()  # Wait for the gRPC thread to finish
```

I am checking log from the window I run "python3 post_service_server.py" and this is all I can see

```
python3 post_service_server.py 
 * Serving Flask app 'post_service_server'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:50056
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 444-907-812
```

Can someone please help to be able to see the debug logs from the gRPC functions or point me to the exact place to track them? Thank you a lot